# Magento 1.9 getCompanyName from registration form field

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, send-mail

I have a custom module with an event observer that sends an e-mail to the admin as soon as a new user registers.

In my **registration form** i am using also the company field. Now I would like to show the **company name** also in my e-mail to the admin.

How can I call this value?  Everything I tried so far did not work. Who can help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get it from POST request.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('your_field_name')
```

Comment: Now I am trying to get also the Country field but what is field name?   It does not work with 'country' . Any idea?

Comment: Try to do this: $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array()); $country = $data['country'];

Comment: Thanks for your effort but unfortunately it does not work (it does not show the country value).

Comment: Get country input name from phtml template and write here. I will try to help you.